# Android: Pass data between activities

Tags: android

I am creating an application named e-wardrobe, users will fill some inputs such as "type of cloth", "season", "color". I want when user writes winter, for example, into the season field, the app will pass type and color strings, into the WinterActivity but i don't know how to do this. I hope you will help me, thanx in advance :)

Comment: have you search title in google at all? you will find many many sample code and tutorial.

Comment: did you even bother googling it ? search for `intent.putExtra` to get started.

Comment: yes i did and i tried some things but they didn't work. :(

Comment: then show us what you have tried, what problems are you facing ? show some errors and `code`, otherwise no one would help you.

Comment: please show the code that you have tried that is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can check the season field then determine what Activity to start from that field and then place the other information you want to pass along with it inside the intent as a bundle. Or better yet dont make a winter activity just make a SeasonActivity and just pass in all the other information and then let the activity decide what it needs to look like and what data it should share with the user.

The data passing from A -> B is in an intent

but from A -> B(dialog or second step) -> is done via ActivityForResult

Comment: Its better to let the OP show some efforts before giving away the entire solution.

Comment: didn't give any code help :) just the theory. i will only ever help with code if they have code that they have written and need help with

Answer (score 0):

You need to add bundle data to a launch intent like this

```
//create the intent and bundle
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(
MenuActivity.this, com.you.AnotherActivity.class);
Bundle extraData = new Bundle();

//assign some values to the bundle
extraData.putSerializable("key1", "value");

//assign bundle to launchIntent
launchIntent.putExtra("keyBundle", extraData);

//start the activity
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Then retrieve the data in the other activity like this:

```
//create a new intent to put the one that started this activity
Intent intent = getIntent();

//retrieve the bundle that was sent in the intent
Bundle recievedBundle = 
        intent.getBundleExtra("keyBundle");


//get the bundle passed from the activity that started this one
MyVariableInAnotherActivity =  recievedBundle.getSerializable("key1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, WinterActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("cloth", clothTextField.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("color", colorTextField.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

In the Winter Activity you receive them like:

```
String cloth = getIntent().getStringExtra("cloth");
String color = getIntent().getStringExtra("color");
```

Hope it helps!!!